# div with position:fixed and 100% height can't scroll

Tags: html, css, scrollbar, multiple-columns, fixed

Why doesn't my right column scroll? Also, how can I have the scrollbar of my left column on right side of my left column because when my two columns have contents, the scroll of the two columns are in the same place.

I've `position:fixed` with `height:100%`.

[Here is a live website.](http://www.500milligrammes.com/fmzz/final/news/ztest/)

Here's the code:

```
<body id="top">
  <div style="height: 100%;" id="container">
    <div style="height: 100%; width:100%; position:absolute;" id="o-wrapper" class="o-wrapper">
      <div class="columnsContainer">
        <div class="leftColumn">
          <div style=" margin:0px auto; border:0px solid #fff; width:auto;">
            <div class="lazy">
              <img class="imgstylefirst" src="img/3.jpg" alt="" />
              <br/>
              <div class="creditstyle">
                Crop Top, Six Crisp Days. Skirt, Topshop. Clutch, Fendi. Rings, Amarilo and Pushmataaha. Shoes, Boohoo.
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="lazy">
              <img class="imgstyle" src="img/2.jpg" alt="" />
              <br/>
              <div class="creditstyle">
                Rings, Amarilo, Pushmataaha and Push&amp;Co.
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="lazy">
              <img class="imgstyle" src="img/4.jpg" alt="" />
              <br/>
              <div class="creditstyle">
                Top, Six Crisp Days. Shawl, Unif. Rings, Amarilo.
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="lazy">
              <img class="imgstyle" src="img/5.jpg" alt="" />
              <br/>
              <div class="creditstyle">
                Jacket, AZUL by moussy. Earrings, Artelier Mx. Rings, Amarilo.
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="lazy">
              <img class="imgstyle" src="img/6.jpg" alt="" />
              <br/>
              <div class="creditstyle">
                Jacket, AZUL by moussy. Earrings, Artelier Mx. Rings, Amarilo.
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="rightColumn">
          <div style="padding:70px 0px 50px 0px; margin: 0px 20px;">
            <a href="#">PREVIOUS</a>
            &nbsp;&nbsp;|&nbsp;&nbsp;
            <a href="#">ALL</a>
            &nbsp;&nbsp;|&nbsp;&nbsp;
            <a href="#">NEXT</a>
          </div>


          <div style="margin: 0px 20px;">
            <span style="100%" class="newstitle">Y</span>
            <p style="margin-top:-7px;">Preview</p>
            <hr style="margin: 15px 0 30px 0;" class="gridnews">
            <div class="flipper">ONE</div>
            <div style="margin:10px 0px 40px 0px; display:block" class="flip">
              blablabla
            </div>
            <div class="flipper">TWO</div>
            <div style="margin:10px 0px 80px 0px;" class="flip">
              Photographer
              <br/>Stylist
              <br/>Makeup
              <br/>Hair
              <br/>Model
              <br/>Photographer
              <br/>Stylist
              <br/>Makeup
              <br/>Hair
              <br/>Model
              <br/>Photographer
              <br/>Stylist
              <br/>Makeup
              <br/>Hair
              <br/>Model
              <br/>Photographer
              <br/>Stylist
              <br/>Makeup
              <br/>Hair
              <br/>Model
              <br/>Photographer
              <br/>Stylist
              <br/>Makeup
              <br/>Hair
              <br/>Model
              <br/>Photographer
              <br/>Stylist
              <br/>Makeup
              <br/>Hair
              <br/>Model
              <br/>Photographer
              <br/>Stylist
              <br/>Makeup
              <br/>Hair
              <br/>Model
              <br/>Photographer
              <br/>Stylist
              <br/>Makeup
              <br/>Hair
              <br/>Model
              <br/>Photographer
              <br/>Stylist
              <br/>Makeup
              <br/>Hair
              <br/>Model
              <br/>Photographer
              <br/>Stylist
              <br/>Makeup
              <br/>Hair
              <br/>Model
              <br/>Photographer
              <br/>Stylist
              <br/>Makeup
              <br/>Hair
              <br/>Model
              <br/>Photographer
              <br/>Stylist
              <br/>Makeup
              <br/>Hair
              <br/>Model
              <br/>Photographer
              <br/>Stylist
              <br/>Makeup
              <br/>Hair
              <br/>Model
              <br/>Photographer
              <br/>Stylist
              <br/>Makeup
              <br/>Hair
              <br/>Model
              <br/>Photographer
              <br/>Stylist
              <br/>Makeup
              <br/>Hair
              <br/>Model
              <br/>Photographer
              <br/>Stylist
              <br/>Makeup
              <br/>Hair
              <br/>Model
              <br/>Photographer
              <br/>Stylist
              <br/>Makeup
              <br/>Hair
              <br/>Model
              <br/>Photographer
              <br/>Stylist
              <br/>Makeup
              <br/>Hair
              <br/>Model
              <br/>Photographer
              <br/>Stylist
              <br/>Makeup
              <br/>Hair
              <br/>Model
              <br/>Photographer
              <br/>Stylist
              <br/>Makeup
              <br/>Hair
              <br/>Model
              <br/>Photographer
              <br/>Stylist
              <br/>Makeup
              <br/>Hair
              <br/>Model
              <br/>Photographer
              <br/>Stylist
              <br/>Makeup
              <br/>Hair
              <br/>Model
              <br/>Photographer
              <br/>Stylist
              <br/>Makeup
              <br/>Hair
              <br/>Model
              <br/>Photographer
              <br/>Stylist
              <br/>Makeup
              <br/>Hair
              <br/>Model
              <br/>Photographer
              <br/>Stylist
              <br/>Makeup
              <br/>Hair
              <br/>Model
              <br/>Photographer
              <br/>Stylist
              <br/>Makeup
              <br/>Hair
              <br/>Model
              <br/>Photographer
              <br/>Stylist
              <br/>Makeup
              <br/>Hair
              <br/>Model
              <br/>Photographer
              <br/>Stylist
              <br/>Makeup
              <br/>Hair
              <br/>Model
              <br/>Photographer
              <br/>Stylist
              <br/>Makeup
              <br/>Hair
              <br/>Model
              <br/>Photographer
              <br/>Stylist
              <br/>Makeup
              <br/>Hair
              <br/>Model
              <br/>Photographer
              <br/>Stylist
              <br/>Makeup
              <br/>Hair
              <br/>Model
              <br/>Photographer
              <br/>Stylist
              <br/>Makeup
              <br/>Hair
              <br/>Model
              <br/>Photographer
              <br/>Stylist
              <br/>Makeup
              <br/>Hair
              <br/>Model
              <br/>Photographer
              <br/>Stylist
              <br/>Makeup
              <br/>Hair
              <br/>Model
              <br/>Photographer
              <br/>Stylist
              <br/>Makeup
              <br/>Hair
              <br/>Model
              <br/>Photographer
              <br/>Stylist
              <br/>Makeup
              <br/>Hair
              <br/>Model
              <br/>Photographer
              <br/>Stylist
              <br/>Makeup
              <br/>Hair
              <br/>Model
              <br/>Photographer
              <br/>Stylist
              <br/>Makeup
              <br/>Hair
              <br/>Model
              <br/>Photographer
              <br/>Stylist
              <br/>Makeup
              <br/>Hair
              <br/>Model
              <br/>Photographer
              <br/>Stylist
              <br/>Makeup
              <br/>Hair
              <br/>Model
              <br/>Photographer
              <br/>Stylist
              <br/>Makeup
              <br/>Hair
              <br/>Model
              <br/>Photographer
              <br/>Stylist
              <br/>Makeup
              <br/>Hair
              <br/>Model
              <br/>Photographer
              <br/>Stylist
              <br/>Makeup
              <br/>Hair
              <br/>Model
              <br/>Photographer
              <br/>Stylist
              <br/>Makeup
              <br/>Hair
              <br/>Model
              <br/>
            </div>
            <div style="margin-top:20px;" class="flipper">THREE</div>
            <div style="margin-top:10px;" class="flip">
              blablabla
            </div>
            <div style="margin-top:20px;" class="flipper">FOUR</div>
            <div style="margin-top:10px;" class="flip">
              blablabla
            </div>
            <div style="margin-top:20px;" class="flipper">FIVE</div>
            <div style="margin-top:10px;" class="flip">
              blablabla
            </div>
            <div style="margin-top:20px;" class="flipper">SIX</div>
            <div style="margin-top:10px;" class="flip">
              blablabla
            </div>
            <div style="margin-top:20px;" class="flipper">SEVEN</div>
            <div style="margin-top:10px;" class="flip">
              blablabla
            </div>
            <div style="margin-top:20px;" class="flipper">EIGHT</div>
            <div style="margin-top:10px;" class="flip">
              blablabla
            </div>
            <div style="margin-top:20px;" class="flipper">NINE</div>
            <div style="margin-top:10px;" class="flip">
              blablabla
            </div>
            <div style="margin-top:20px;" class="flipper">TEN</div>
            <div style="margin-top:10px;" class="flip">
              blablabla
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: What exactly do you want to happen? Your right column scrolls fine when it needs to in Chrome.

Comment: @Alan in firefox you can find the problem, just resize your page, And i think it's better to have the scrollbar of the left column at right of the left column, No ?

Comment: Ok, I can see the issue in FF. The answer suggested below seems to allow both columns to scroll

Comment: yes but when you resize your page,  you can't see all the content of the right column, why ?

Comment: The answer below solves the problem, but it is not a nice page or user experience. I suggest you try a different page structure.

Comment: ok @Brett i think on it now ;) thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fix your styles like this:

```
.columnsContainer {
    height: 100%;
}

.leftColumn {
    margin-right: 600px;
    background: #fff;
    height: 100%;
    overflow-y: scroll;
}
```

These changes seem to work for me.

Comment: that's perfect @Hieu Le but how can i fix the problem with the scroll for the right column. When you resize your page ( less height ) you can't see the rest of the div ( six, seven, eight, ...)

Comment: it looks like your site is better. you added the overflow-y: auto to your rightclolumn class. I would suggest adding top: 0 to your rightColumn class so that the scrollbar starts from the top